# Signalr invode not return output xml, angularjs

Tags: xml, angularjs

For SPA have to use angularjs, signalr. Signalr call require xml as a input parameter based on input xml, output xml will return which I have to parse and get essential data.
Parse data contain captions/labels which to be used on HTML page to be set through  controller.

When called through invoke method it is not returned output xml in data.
Here is the code.

```
function ServerTimeController($scope, signalRHubProxy) {

            var serverHubProxy = signalRHubProxy(
                signalRHubProxy.defaultServer, 'serverTimeHub');

            $scope.getServerData = function () {
                serverHubProxy.invoke('getBnoData', '
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ENVELOPE NAME="PV.ENVELOPE" VERSION="1.00" CREATE="">
      <ENVELOPE_DATA>
        <TOKEN />
        <IPADDRESS />
        <USERAGENT />
        <LANGUAGE>LANGUAGE:ENGLISH</LANGUAGE>
        <ORIGINATOR>PV.TC.WEB.UI</ORIGINATOR>
      </ENVELOPE_DATA>
      <APPLICATION_REQUEST VERSION="1.00" LANGUAGE="EN">
        <BNO_REQUEST VERSION="1.00">
          <BNO_PRODUCTION_MODE>TRUE</BNO_PRODUCTION_MODE>
          <BNO_GROUP>LOGIN</BNO_GROUP>
          <BNO_INTERACTION_NAME>GET_T_PRE_APP_INIT</BNO_INTERACTION_NAME>
          <BNO_INTERACTION_VERSION>1.00</BNO_INTERACTION_VERSION>
          <BNO_INTERACTION_MODE>INTERACTION_MODE:VIEW</BNO_INTERACTION_MODE>
          <BNO_PARAMETERS>
            <BNO_PARAM NAME="LINGO">
              <VALUE>EN</VALUE>
            </BNO_PARAM>
          </BNO_PARAMETERS>
        </BNO_REQUEST>
      </APPLICATION_REQUEST>
    </ENVELOPE>
    ', function (data) {
                    $scope.currentServerTimeManually = data;
                    console.log(data);
                });
            };
        };
```

Factory code

```
app1.factory('signalRHubProxy', ['$rootScope', 'signalRServer',
    function ($rootScope, signalRServer) {
        function signalRHubProxyFactory(serverUrl, hubName, startOptions) {
            var connection = $.hubConnection(signalRServer);
            var proxy = connection.createHubProxy("pvhub");
            connection.start(startOptions).done(function () { });

            return {
                on: function (eventName, callback) {
                    proxy.on(eventName, function (result) {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            if (callback) {
                                callback(result);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                },
                off: function (eventName, callback) {
                    proxy.off(eventName, function (result) {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            if (callback) {
                                callback(result);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                },
                invoke: function (methodName, input, callback) {
                    proxy.invoke(methodName, input)
                        .done(function (result) {
                            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                                if (callback) {
                                    callback(result);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                },
                connection: connection
            };
        };

        return signalRHubProxyFactory;    
}]);
```

However when used  srv.client.receiveData it gives output xml but I need to integrate this in angularjs.

Hub code is here:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;

using IDF.FACADE;

namespace PV.COM.WEB
{
    public class PvHub : Hub
    {
        ///
<summary> /// Function to be called from client siede
  /// </summary>
///
<param name="piAppRequest">
</param>
public void GetBnoData(string piAppRequest)
        {

...deleted code here

             /// call BackendAPI (Facade) to retrieve XML with content.
                    callFacade = new Facade("PV.GLOBAL.APPCONFIG.XML");
                    answer = callFacade.ExecuteAppRequest(piAppRequest);

...deleted code here

            /// call function on JS client side to send XML data with content filled by Facade 
             Clients.Caller.receiveData(answer);
        }

...deleted code here

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add you Hub's code? It is not clear how you return data from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few things that do not look right, but the most clear to me is the fact that you are sending your data to the caller invoking `receiveData` on it, however you did not define any `receiveData` handler in your client code.

**UPDATE**

As I said, you have no `receiveData` callback defined on the client, but adding that would have an impact on your current client code organization. It's not a difficult thing to do, but you'd have to change some stuff. Instead, if you just change your `Hub` code from:

```
public void GetBnoData(string piAppRequest)
{
    //getting answer...

    Clients.Caller.receiveData(answer);
}
```

to

```
public dynamic GetBnoData(string piAppRequest)  //from void to dynamic
{
    //getting answer...

    return answer;
}
```

then you current client code (based on `.done(...)`) will just work.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to call receiveData in angularjs factory code

Comment: Thank you, issue was I called receiveData after connection established which should always before. Now abled to catch data.